# Typescript HOC with redux connect

Tags: typescript, redux, higher-order-components

I am trying create a HOC with redux' connect wrapping some other component. However I cannot seem to get the arguments of the connect generic right. Other guides on this topic I found have either barely scratched the surface or are going right over my head. I would appreciate some help on this. This is my code so far:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import {StoreState} from '../reducers'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

interface Props{
  auth: boolean
}

interface OwnProps {

}

export default (ChildComponent: React.ComponentType): React.ComponentType<typeof ChildComponent>=> {
  class ComposedComponent extends React.Component<Props> {

  componentDidMount(): void{
    this.shouldNavigateAway()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(): void {
    this.shouldNavigateAway()
  }

  shouldNavigateAway = (): void => {
    if (!this.props.auth) {
      //do something
    }
  }

    render(): ReactElement {
      return <ChildComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = ({
    auth,
  }: StoreState): {auth: boolean} => {
    return { auth }
  }

  return connect<Props, {}, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps)(ComposedComponent)
}
```

The error I am getting is solely on the 'mapStateToProps' in my return statement at the very end and it says:

```
const mapStateToProps: ({ auth, }: StoreState) => {
    auth: boolean;
}
Argument of type '({ auth, }: StoreState) => { auth: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<Props, OwnProps, DefaultRootState>'.
  Type '({ auth, }: StoreState) => { auth: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToPropsFactory<Props, OwnProps, DefaultRootState>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'initialState' are incompatible.
      Type 'DefaultRootState' is missing the following properties from type 'StoreState': comments, authts(2345)
```

My StoreState interface looks as follows:

```
export interface StoreState {
  comments: Comment[]
  auth: boolean
}
```

However I feel like I do need its return type the way it is. I have already tried omitting the comments part of my state since the HOC is only responsible for the auth property but in that case the error will still complain that 'auth' is missing. Kinda stuck here and not sure where TS is trying to point me.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the React-Redux usage guide page on "Static Typing"](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing), you actually shouldn't be trying to declare the generics in `connect` directly.  In fact, we specifically recommend using [the `ConnectedProps<T>` technique](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically) described in that page to automatically infer the type of all the props being passed from `connect` to your own component.

Comment: Thanks! This might be a specific question but i still think this to be valid

I have `component.tsx` and `index.tsx`, `index.ts` contains `connect` logic and imports `component.tsx`. Now if I export `ConnectedProps` from `index.ts` and use it in `component.tsx` it creates cyclic dependency. The only option I have is to create a third file. 

The issue with this is boilerplate and feel unscalable.

Comment: Type-level cyclic imports are fine most of the time, because they're _compile_-time cycles.  It's _runtime_  imports that are normally an issue.  That said, today you really should be using the React-Redux hooks API and following our recommended TS usage guidelines for declaring "pre-typed" hooks: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start#define-typed-hooks